# Derivates and Integrals

Tags: integration, derivatives

If I take the integral of the derivative of $y=x^2$, what does it equal, $x^2+c$ or $x^2$? I think it equals $x^2+c$, but my friend says that by taking the derivative you get $2x$ and then when integrating, you can assume $c=0$ from the original equation. What's the correct answer?

Comment: You can only assume $c=0$ if you have prior knowledge of some *system* whose evolution is modelled by $y'=2x$, This prior knowledge is known as *initial conditions*.

Comment: $$
\int \left( \frac{d}{dx} x^2 \right)\ dx = x^2 + c \\
\frac{d}{dx} \left( \int x^2\ dx \right) = x^2
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you take *indefinite* integral (a.k.a. antiderivative) of function $f(x)$, you basically search for all functions $F(x)$ such that $F'(x)$ is defined whenever $f$ is and in all those points $F'(x) = f(x)$. The problem is, there are many possible $F$. If $f(x)$ is defined on a continuous interval, for any two solutions $F_1, F_2$ it can be shown that $F_1(x) - F_2(x) = C$ where $C$ is some number. In other words, *in this case* all solutions to, say, $F'(x) = 2x$ can be neatly described as $F(x) = x^2 + C$ where $C \in \mathbb{R}$.
You *can't* just assume $C=0$, since $F(x) = x^2+42$ fits your initial question just as fine. But since the family of solutions is very simple, sometimes people just write $\int 2x \, dx = x^2$ - omitting repetitive $C$ to save some space.

Note that in other cases family of solutions is trickier than that. Take $f(x) = {1 \over x^2}$. You can often meet the statement $\int {dx \over x^2} = -{1 \over x} + C$. But for
$$F(x) = \cases{10 -  {1 \over x} | x < 0 \\ 42 - {1 \over x} | x > 0}$$
$F'(x) = f(x)$ whenever $f(x)$ is defined, as well.

In other words. $\int 2x \, dx$ is a set of functions $F$ which can be described as $x^2 + C$ where $C$ runs through all $\mathbb{R}$. One of the function in this set is $x^2$. Unless you have some reason to prefer this solution to another (like added constraint $F(0) = 0$), you can't just throw that $C$ away.

Answer (score 1):

if we integrate $$2x$$ with respect to $x$ we get $$x^2+C$$ since we differentiate this result with respect to $$x$$ we get $$2x$$. Note that $$C'=0$$

Comment: The OP was asking about going to opposite way to what you have described here

Answer (score 1):

This is the statement of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.  We know that  $\int f(x) dx = F(x)$ where $F(x)$ has the property that $F'(x) = f(x)$.  Then you have to know that $F'(x) = G'(x)$ if and only if $F(x)-G(x)= c$ where $c$ is a constant.  Then when you integrate a function you get any anti derivative which in this case is $x^2+c$.

Basically even if you started with $x^2$ if you integrate after differentiating you get $x^2 + c$.  This is because integrating gives a family of functions where as taking the derivative gives one particular function.

Comment: Fundamental Theorem deals with *definite* integrals, like $\int_0^1x^2 \, dx$ and essentially states that ${d \over dx}(\int_a^x f(t) \, dt) \equiv f(x)$. That has little relevance to OP question.

Answer (score 1):

The key fact is that the derivation $\frac{d}{dx}$ of a function of the variable $x$ is an operator that is not invertible, just because the derivative of a function $f(x)$ is the same as the derivative of the function $f(x)+c$ (where $c$ is a constant).

So whan ve derive $f(x)=x^2$ we find $ \frac{d}{dx} (x^2)=2x$, but the *antiderivative* ( i.e. the inverse of the derivation) of $2x$ is  ''multi valued'' and gives all the function of the form $x^2+c$.

Answer (score 0):

$y = x^2$

On differentiate,

$\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x$

$dy = 2x dx$

On integration,

$y = 2 \cdot \frac{x^2}{2} + c$

$y = x^2 + c$

So now decide yourself.